# SQL how to SELECT all utf8mb4 characters?

Tags: mysql, sql, utf-8, ascii, utf8mb4

I have this query:

```
SELECT count(*) from TABLE WHERE LENGTH(COLUMN) !=CHAR_LENGTH(COLUMN);
```

If count returns a value more than zero it tell me that I have non-ASCII characters in some row.

How I can know if I have utf8mb4 characters in the TABLE?

Is there a way to query all utf8mb4 characters?

Comment: Do the MySQL functions [CHARSET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_charset) and/or
[COLLATION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_collation) help? I.e. `select charset(col) from tab`? It's just a guess and might be that they return only what the columns are set up to, not their actual content.

Comment: This doesn't help me, I already know that that table has utf8mb4_unicode_ci collation. What I need is to know if characters in 4 bytes are really stored in it.

Comment: Whit this `select * from TABLE where LENGTH(COLUMN) != CHAR_LENGTH(COLUMN);` I can select that rows, but I can't know if there are really utf8mb4 characters in them.

Comment: That's what I assumed. It was just an idea when I saw these functions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "utf8mb4 characters".  This sentence is entirely composed of "utf8mb4 characters".  This sentence is entirely composed of "ascii" characters.

Assuming you meant "non-ASCII" *and* the column is `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4`, then your query should work fine.

This technique works for any of the multi-byte character sets, such as utf8, big5, etc.  It does not work for single-byte character sets such as latin1, latin5, etc.

If you want to extract the non-ascii bytes from the column, that would be better done in some application language.  It might have a straightforward way of doing that, or you could fetch the HEX and look for some pair of hex with regexp `[CDEF].`

If you meant "utf8mb4" but not "utf8", then the hex would be `F.`  And the row can be discovered via

```
HEX(col) RLIKE "^(..)*F."
```

Comment: Thank's, could you explain your Regex `RLIKE "^(..)*F."`, please?

Comment: From the beginning, `^`, of the string, look for zero or more, `*`, 2-character, `..`, strings, then an `F` followed by another character, `.`.  (The final `.` is not really necessary.)  The `()` are for grouping to make the pairs of hex characters 'work'.

Comment: The encoding for 4-byte UTF8 characters (that is, those that are in mysql's utf8mb4, but not in mysql's utf8), start with hex `F`.  See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) and many other references.